# Converting a groupby output into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with the *Northwind* database ([download link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m61r928dxt3fcp3/AACLdakXmluJ__II4mt_PpU7a?dl=0), [documentation](http://dbdesc.com/output_samples/htmlbrowse_northwind.html)).

I wanted to check the popularity of sold products, I did it in the following way

```
order_details_products = order_details.merge(products, on = 'productID')
order_details_products_categories = order_details_products.merge(categories, on = 'categoryID')

popularity_products = order_details_products_categories.groupby(['productID', 
                                                                 'categoryID', 
                                                                 'categoryName']).agg(no_orders 
                                                                                      = ('productID', 
                                                                                         'count'))
popularity_products.sort_values(by = 'no_orders', ascending = False, inplace = True)
```

It works and it perfectly returns what I need. However there's an issue I don't know how to deal with. When I check the shape of my dataframe *popularity_products* I get the following output

```
popularity_products.shape
Out[27]: (77, 1)
```

That means that my dataframe contains only one column: *no_orders*. Is it possible to make a dataframe with 4 columns: *productID, categoryID, categoryName*?

Regards.

Comment: just add `reset_index` or `.to_frame` to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible to use:

```
popularity_products = popularity_products.to_frame().reset_index()
```

Comment: There's no attribute *to_frame* according to Spyder.

Comment: In that case try just `popularity_products = popularity_products.reset_index()`